# XSLT Design for XML code

Tags: xslt

Hi I am a fresher and it would be helpful if you answer my question.

Consider my XML

```
<A>
<B>
 <b1>a</b1>
 <b2>b</b2>
</B>
<C>
 <c1>a</c1>
 <c2>b</c2>
</C>
</A>.
```

In XSLT I need to find out the number of sub childdren of nodes B and C.
If there are 2 children in B then the XSLT dynamically print #1 a and #2 b.
Similarly if there are n children #1 value, #2 value ............ #n value.
Please help in in solving this. I need XSLT design code for the above condition.

Comment: Can you give a precise example of how you want your output XML to look. Also, can you show any XSLT you have tried already. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your goal... - could you please add an example output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "dynamically" output the value of an element and with the "number" of the child as prefix you can use `xsl:value-of select="position()"/>`

Assuming your output should be text (not xml) try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*"  mode ="printChildNr" >
        <!-- children of B or C-->
        <xsl:text>children of </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>:&#10; </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="*" >
            <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <!-- text content of child-->
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="B | C"  mode="printChildNr"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `mode="printChildNr"` is not necessary  but may help if you have to extend the xlt.

input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<A>
    <B>
        <b1>a</b1>
        <b2>b</b2>
    </B>
    <C>
        <c1>a</c1>
        <c2>b</c2>
        <c3>b</c3>
    </C>
</A>
```

Output:

```
 children of B:
 #1 a
 #2 b
 children of C:
 #1 a
 #2 b
 #3 b
```

Comment: @NTR Thanku so much for the reply.But I am facing 2 issues.First thing u have used * here instead I need to use B/b1.But all the children of B are dynamically generated.Second thing is that I want each result in a separate td.

Comment: You are being very unclear. If you need the output in a td element, why didn't you say so in the first place? If the children are dynamically generated, do you know their names in advance, or don't you?

Comment: Sorry!!!Actually I got ur point but the XML is created at run time.What ever might be the child nodes on node B i want them to be printed #1: value #2: value. Sorry again for the inconvinience caused.